# Sum TimeField hours/minutes with Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am trying to use Pandas to sum the time (hours, minutes) of a series.  The data comes from a TimeField

```
class PhoneRecord ( models.Model ):
    et = models.TimeField ( null=True, blank=True )
```

In python I get the record and convert to a dataframe.

```
phone = PhoneRecord.objects.all()

df = read_frame ( phone )

df.et = df.et.fillna ( '00:00:00' )    # some records are blank

df [ "time" ] = pd.to_datetime(df.et, format = '%H:%M:%S', errors = 'coerce')
```

this gives me the following output.

```
0      00:00:35
1      00:00:29
2      00:00:00
3      00:00:00
4      00:00:37
       ......
```

When I try to sum

```
df.time.sum ()
```

I get errors like:  unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

What do I need to do to be able to sum and average the data.

Thank you.

Comment: Convert to timedelta and find the mean: `pd.to_timedelta(df.time).mean()
# Timedelta('0 days 00:00:20.200000')`

Comment: sorry, not sure about this:  "Convert to timedelta". Thanks.

Comment: The code to run is also in the same comment, take a look.

Comment: I put in a print() and for this error:  Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: sorry this is not my day job - obviously.

Comment: ok, think I got something. -25567 days +00:01:22.572972

Comment: this is a mean.  the sum does not work?   print(pd.to_timedelta(df.time).sum())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You just need to run a custom 1-liner here to combine `time` objects into `timedelta` objects which can then be summed together.  (see the "print" line)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

phone = PhoneRecord.objects.all()
df = pd.DataFrame(list([i.__dict__ for i in phone])) # create pd.df from model query
df.et = df.et.fillna('00:00:00')  # some records are blank
print(df.et)
print("SUM:", sum([datetime.combine(datetime.min, time) - datetime.min for time in df.et.tolist()], timedelta()))
```

You should get something like this:

```
0    00:00:20
1    00:00:20
2    00:00:50
3    00:00:30
4    00:00:20

SUM: 0:02:20
```

I had to change things a bit to get them to work on my end so hopefully, it is the same with you and your version of Pandas and Django. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

All computations, such as getting averages, counting etc. should be performed (if possible) using database engine. I don't know about underlying problem, but using `pandas` on the server-side to get average values is definitely overkill. You need to look at [aggregation facility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/) of Django.

Also, you probably need to restructure the model. If you need to store duration of a phone conversation, you can use FloatField instead, e.g.

```
class PhoneRecord(models.Model):
    duration = models.FloatField(blank=True, default=0.0, help_text=_('duration in seconds')) 
    # other fields... 
    # also, you can set up  the duration field with `editable=False`, and 
    # calculate its value each time the record is created
```

In this case you can use  `Avg`:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
PhoneRecords.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('duration'))
```

and get something like this

```
{'duration_avg': 12.3}
```